# NameError in Empresa#new uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Empresas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Error:

```
SyntaxError
/root/projeto/config/routes.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end get "/empresa/new" to: 'empresa#new' 
^ /root/projeto/config/routes.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end post "/empresas" to: 'empresa#create' ^
```

Code:

```
<%= form_for Empresas.new do |f| %>
  <div class = "form-group">
    <%= f.label :nome %>
    <%= f.text_field :nome , class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :endereco %>
    <%= f.text_field :endereco, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <%= f.submit "Criar", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
    class EmpresaController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @empresa = Empresa.order :nome
    end

   def new
  @empresa = Empresa.new
end

def create
  valores = params.require(:empresa).permit :nome, :endereco
  @empresa= Empresa.create  valores
  if @empresa.save
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render :new
  end
end
end
```

Routes:
Here are the routes of user and company.
User routes are not called at any time from your company code.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
        post "/usuarios" => "usuario#create"
        get "/usuario/new" => "usuario#new"
        delete "/usuario/:id" => "usuario#destroy", as:  :usuario
        get "/usuario/busca" => "usuario#busca", as: :busca_usuario
        root to: "usuario#index"
        get "/usuario/lista" => "usuario#lista"
        get "/empresa/index" => "empresa#index"
        get "/empresa/new" to: 'empresa#new'
        post "/empresas" to: 'empresa#create'
    end
```

Comment: See your last two routes, you need to separate the URI definition with the method with commas. Try `get "/empresa/new", to: 'empresa#new'
  post "/empresas", to: 'empresa#create'`

Comment: That worked, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the singular way for your model when you use the `form_for` helper:

```
<%= form_for Empresa.new do |f| %>
```

Also to maintain the MVC pattern you could create an instance variable equal to `Empresa.new` in your controller and then pass it to the form.

You could take a look to the [Rails helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html).

Try editing your controller like:

```
# app/controllers/empresa_controller.rb
...
def new
  @empresa = Empresa.new
end

def create
  valores = params.require(:empresa).permit :nome, :endereco
  @empresa= Empresa.create  valores
  if @empresa.save
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

And be sure in your routes you have both methods:

```
# config/routes.rb
get '/empŕesa/new', to: 'empresa#new'
post '/empresas', to: 'empresa#create'
```

Then in your `new` view you'll have the variable `@empresa` defined in the `new` method, you can use it in your form:

```
# app/views/empresa/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @empresa do |f| %>
```

**Update**: The last update to the question shows you were missing the commas in the route definitions.

Comment: This change the error, now is:  
NoMethodError in Empresa#new

Showing /root/projeto/app/views/empresa/new.html.erb where line #4 raised:

undefined method `empresas_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fd70c1cb8b8>:0x007fd719fed1c8>
Did you mean?  empresa_new_path

Comment: Try setting `empresa_new_path` instead `empresas_path`, or add your routes to the question.

Comment: Routes:   
  `get "/empresa/index" => "empresa#index"`
 
  `get "/empresa/new" => "empresa#new"`

Comment: Doesn't `empresa_new_path` work?, what's on `new.html.erb`?

Comment: How can I do this, include empresa_new_path and where do I do this?

Comment: Where are you getting such route error? That doesn't appear in your question, that's why asked what's in your new.html.erb.

Comment: I'm getting it in my browser, when I ask for the application to run. `
   <%= form_for @empresa_c do |f| %>            <div class = "form-group"> <%= f.label :nome %>   <%= f.text_field :nome , class: "form-control" %>  </div>
          <div class="form-group">   <%= f.label :endereco %>
              <%= f.text_field :endereco, class: "form-control" %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                  <%= f.submit "Criar", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
              </div>
          </div>
 <% end %>`

Comment: What's `@empresa_c`, how have you defined that variable?

Comment: @empresa_c =  Empresa.new

Comment: In your `new` method? Have you modified your routes?

Comment: I did not modify the routes, I do not know how to do it, and this variable I put in the controller.

Comment: Try instead with `Empresa.new` in the `form_for` instead the variable, to see what happens.

Comment: NoMethodError in Empresa#new

Showing /root/projeto/app/views/empresa/new.html.erb where line #4 raised:

undefined method `empresas_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fd70c366308>:0x007fd70c835ed8>
Did you mean?  empresa_new_path

Comment: So, now, how does your `empresas#new` method looks like?

Comment: The `empresa#new` would call my controller's create method, right?

Comment: Yes, from new to create, you need to make your routes match with your methods in your controllers, that's the reason of such error. Try with: `def new @empresa_c  =  Empresa.new end`.

Comment: So, I put it the way it is there, but it keeps giving error


SyntaxError
/root/project/config/routes.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end get "/ company / new" to: 'company # new' ^ /root/project/config/routes.rb:10: syntax Error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end post "/ companies" to: 'company # create' ^
Extracted source (around line # 9):     
      >     
    get "/empresa/index" => "empresa#index"
  get "/empresa/new" to: 'empresa#new'
  post "/empresas" to: 'empresa#create'
end

End

Comment: You have an syntax error in your routes, I can't see which one or where. Do you have a repository?

Comment: A repository? I did not understand. I have several routes configured, but of other classes, this does not influence anything?

Comment: It's just there's a long thread and I can't figure out where's the problem, I'd need to see more details, if you add files involved in the problem. Try adding your routes to the question.